# If the images of $m_1, \dots, m_r$ in $S^{-1}M$ generate the module, then so do their images in $M_f$, for some $f \in S$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, localization

> Suppose $R$ is a ring and $M$ is a finitely generated module such that the images of $m_1, \dots, m_r$ in $S^{-1}M$ generate $S^{-1}M$ as a $S^{-1}R$-module. Then prove that the images of $m_1, \dots, m_r$ in $M_f$, generate $M_f$ as a $R_f$-module, for some $f \in S$.

This is a homework problem but I spent a few hours and didn't get very far:

Let $x \in M$ and $M = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$, where the $a_i \in M$. Then, we have that $x = c_1 a_1 + c_2 a_2 + \cdots + c_n a_n$, where the $c_i \in R$. Let $s \in S$. Then $\frac{x}{s}$ can be written as $\frac{x}{s} = \frac{b_1m_1}{s_1} + \frac{b_2m_2}{s_2} + \cdots + \frac{b_rm_r}{s_r}$ where the $b_i \in R$ and $m_i \in M$. . I'm almost certain that combining fractions is the way to go but I have no clue how to proceed from where I am at.

Comment: It would help us understand your work if you explained what $x, c_i, a_i$ and $b_i$ are - at the moment it looks like you are writing $1/s$ as a sum of module elements which does not make sense, as $1/s$ is in $S^{-1}R$, which is not part of the module. As far as a hint: you have not used the fact that $M$ is finitely generated yet - what happens if you take a generating set $\{n_k\}$ for $M$ and express the $n_k/1$'s in terms of the $m_i/1$'s.

Comment: @TokenToucan thanks for catching some of my errors. I edited it so that it makes sense. Oh I see where you are getting at. Each of the $n_k$/1's are some linear combination of the $m_i$/1's.

Comment: Set $N=\left< m_1,\dots,m_r\right >$. For every $x\in M$ there is $s\in S$ such that $sx\in N$. Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be a system of generators for $M$ and $s_1,\dots,s_n\in S$ such that $s_ix_i\in N$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. Set $f=s_1\cdots s_n$. Then $fM\subseteq N$ and therefore $M_f=N_f$.